# Adding og:image meta tag to Next project

Tags: next.js

I am trying to add an og:image to my Next app, but can't get it to work. The image is located in the src/app folder. Below is my project's head component:

```
export default function Head() {

  return (
    <>
      <title>Free Vector Illustrations for Your Website</title>
      <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1' name='viewport' />
      <meta
        property='og:title'
        content='Free Vector Illustrations for Your Website'
      />
      <meta property='og:image' content='./ogimage.png' />
      <meta property='og:type' content='website' />
      <meta property='og:url' content='https://www.vectorowl.com/' />
      <meta name='twitter:card' content='summary_large_image' />
      <meta name='twitter:site' content='@_PixelPrism' />
      <meta name='twitter:title' content='Unique Vector Illustrations' />

      <meta
        name='twitter:description'
        content='Enjoy our collections of free vector illustrations'
      />
      <meta name='twitter:image' content='./ogimage.png' />
      <meta
        name='description'
        content='Explore a variety of free vector illustrations to enhance your website. Our vector art is available for download in WebP format. Premium illustrations available.'
      />
      <link rel='icon' href='/favicon.ico' />
    </>
  )
}
```

Comment: are you sure paths `content='./ogimage.png'` are correct